# How do I write PHP and MySQL to display a picture of the day on my website?

Tags: php, mysql, debugging

So I have a blog I wrote in PHP, and it displays the most recent post. How would I write a script that selects from a queued database and automatically updates the new blog post at midnight? I want to rearrange that queued posts in a certain order, such as scheduling picture of the day for a week?

When I manually do it, I have to go to the page `post.php`

```
mysqli_select_db($link, $blogdb);

$clean_post_title = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['post_title']);
$clean_post_text = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['post_text']);
$clean_image_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $file_name);
//create and issue the first query
$add_post_sql = "INSERT INTO forum_posts (post_text, post_create_time, post_owner, post_title, post_image) VALUES ('".$clean_post_text."', ".time().", '".$owner."', '".$clean_post_title ."', '".$clean_image_name."')";

$add_post_res = mysqli_query($link, $add_post_sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));
$get_postID = mysqli_insert_id($link);
```

Comment: `SELECT .... ORDER BY ...`

Comment: I mean sort by and a function that doesn't allow it to post without a scheduler

Comment: What function are you talking about? Where's your code which select posts from your database?

Comment: MySQL `ORDER BY` does sort for you. I don't understand the question? i.e. use `SELECT * FROM \`table\` ORDER BY \`date_posted\``

Comment: are you  asking about cron job/ scheduled task or the php method or sql  ?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something.

Comment: Make sure you have either a `scheduled` column in your post-table, or a separate table with `post-id` and `schedule` and pull from that once each day, via a cron-job, matching the date with today's server-date, and posting what it finds.

Comment: What would the cron job function look like? Currently running phpStorm on a dreamhost basic server. I have heard of these. However, I have a 24 hour desktop pc on at all times., if that's easier.